# Restoring thunderbird mailboxes

Tags: thunderbird

I probably touched some configuration and now I can only see one mailbox on the left-hand side of my screen (while before I had 4).

How can I restore my configuration?

**Troubleshooting information**

View->Folder is set to all.

The other accounts are not deleted since clicking in the little arrow next to get messages I see them listed. Clicking on them does nothing. They are also listed in Edit -> Account Settings

I cannot see a "local folder" folder.

Comment: Did you do View/Folders and then select anything else than "All"? You didn't delete the other accounts? (Edit/Account settings). Do you have the Local Folders folder?

Comment: @Jos 
View->Folder is set to all.

The other accounts are not deleted since clicking in the little arrow next to get messages I see them listed. Clicking on them does nothing. They are also listed in Edit -> Account Settings

I cannot see a "local folder" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing the following sequence fixed the issue:

View - Layout - Folder pane